# I attempted to swap from USDC to SOL, never received SOL but USDC is gone

Tags: transaction, swap, usdc

I initiated a swap, for 20 USDC to SOL. The USDC is no longer in my wallet, and there is no additional Solana. The Solscan is as follows:

https://solscan.io/tx/5TjtcMpfgC2Dnbe3cxDccWkh3ivMsAzz96qCf7b2STW5HZSv1y56ha3EjP6VU5ShNGBK9WygYsh7oHzC3Fh3hait

I looked at a previous transaction where I swapped 15 USDC, and it shows the same exact address at the end, but I don’t understand what that is or who to ask for help. Any help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: I GOT THIS FIGURED OUT, NO HELP IS NEEDED ANY LONGER. HAVE A BLESSED DAY

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. If you could post what the issue was as answer to your question, that would be great in case others have this same problem. Otherwise I'll vote to close this since you don't need any more help.